# Java type casting problems

Tags: java, casting

I have encountered an interesting problem when Java programming. I do not recall that I had such a problem previously. I declared two variables. Type of `x` is `byte` and `y` is `short`. Summation of `x` and `5` cannot be assigned to `y`.

```
    byte x = 3;
    short y = 103;
    y = x + 5;
```

NetBeans gives `possible lossy conversion from int to short` error. However, there is no problem with `y = 5`. I also tried `y = x + (short)5`. But this doesn't work either. Only `y = (short)(x + 5)`works. Moreover, `y = x + x`doesn't work. It is weird. Does Java compiler automatically convert result of any calculation to `int`?

Comment: Did you try `y = (short)x + 5`?

Comment: Short answer: yes, any arithmetic operation on bytes or shorts will be promoted to an int result.  See the linked question for details.

Comment: Java should convert everything to the largest operand type so of short and int is largest. So `x + 5` is int.  I think the compiler is happy to do the conversion from the literal 103 to a short but not a variable. The fix would be to change the calculation to `x + (short)5`